# Obter dados de acordo com data em MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu preciso disponibilizar a opção de visualizar os dados de acordo com um tempo X determinado pelo usuario, por exemplo

Eu quero os dados de 01/03/2011 até 25/12/2014

Como eu posso fazer isso com MySQL? Como eu preciso montar a tabela para que tudo possa correr bem?

Comment: Desfiz o fechamento e a exclusão, percebi que não é bem duplicata daquela outra.

Comment: Mas ainda está um pouco ampla. Sua dúvida é só em relação ao banco de dados?

Comment: Sim, como eu posso obter da data X ate a data Y (query) e como montar a tabela (que tipo usar etc..)

Answer (score 2):

Se você tiver uma 'coluna' com o tipo *DATE*, pode utilizar o seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE coluna > '2011-03-01' AND coluna < '2014-12-25'
```

Se 'coluna' estiver em *DATETIME* pode utilizar o seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE coluna > '2011-03-01 00:00:00' AND coluna < '2014-12-25 00:00:00'
```

Como não foi especificado como está o seu banco da dados, isso aí poderia ajudar.
Logicamente, pode ser utilizado o TIMESTAMP ou o TIME, mas, é só adaptar.